# How Do I call procedures iteratively from a if block in a PLSQL code?

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, block

I am trying to call multiple procedures from a driving procedure in a package. The logic is such that if it encounters a specific value from a lookup table, it should call a specific procedure and continue to call the subsequent procedures for all the subsequent values in that lookup table. The problem is, my code goes into an infinite loop while doing so. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
PROCEDURE TEST(
    a_archiveDays_in             IN NUMBER,
    a_amountInstancesToCommit_in IN NUMBER,
    a_result_out OUT INTEGER,
    a_resultException_out OUT VARCHAR,
    stage_val OUT NUMBER)
IS
  i NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT stage FROM completion_status WHERE status_id IS NOT NULL)
  LOOP
    i := i+1;
    IF rec.stage =1 THEN
      DBMS_output.put_line('Starting Shipment Data population');
      /*populate_shipment_data(a_archiveDays_in ,
      a_resultException_out , a_result_out );*/
    ELSIF rec.stage = 2 THEN
      DBMS_output.put_line('Starting Document data population');
      /* populate_document_data(a_archiveDays_in,
      a_resultException_out , a_result_out);*/
    ELSIF rec.stage =3 THEN
      DBMS_output.put_line('Starting Shipment Archiving');
      shipment_archive (a_archiveDays_in,a_amountInstancesToCommit_in,a_result_out,a_resultException_out );
    ELSIF rec.stage =4 THEN
      DBMS_output.put_line('Starting shipment Master deletion');
      shipment_mast_del (a_archiveDays_in,a_amountInstancesToCommit_in,a_result_out ,a_resultException_out);
    elsif rec.stage =5 THEN
      DBMS_output.put_line('Starting Document Archiving');
      document_archive(a_archiveDays_in,a_amountInstancesToCommit_in,a_result_out ,a_resultException_out );
    elsif rec.stage =0 THEN
      DBMS_output.put_line('Archival Completed...');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_output.put_line('Check Log Table for more info');
WHEN too_many_rows THEN
  DBMS_output.put_line('Not Allowed');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_output.put_line('Check');
  a_result_out          := SQLCODE;
  a_resultException_out := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 3000);
END TEST;
/
```

Comment: without seeing the code it´s highly unlikely one could help you

Comment: Infinite Loop and calling the procedures are not related at all. There might be other problems, for which you should show us some code.

Comment: Hi There, I am new to this place.
Where do I upload my code? :(

Comment: Are you updating/inserting/deleting the table `completion_status` in any of the procedures?

Comment: Yes. In each of the procs, completion_status is updated.Based on the updated value the next block is supposed to be called or the entire operation is supposed to end

Comment: So, my guess is this table has only one record with the stage value?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, my code goes into an infinite loop while doing so.

There is no EXIT statement in your loop. To prevent infinite loop you must use `EXIT` or `EXIT WHEN` or raise an exception wich transfer transfer to the end of the loop.
Please study following links:

---

[Basic LOOP statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS399)

> With each iteration of the loop, the statements run and control returns to the top of the loop. To prevent an infinite loop, a statement or raised exception must exit the loop.

---

[EXIT statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS400)

> The EXIT statement exits the current iteration of a loop
>   unconditionally and transfers control to the end of either the current
>   loop or an enclosing labeled loop.

Simple example:

```
   i := 0;
   LOOP
     ...
     ...
     IF i > 9 THEN
         EXIT;
     END IF;
     i := i + 1;
   END LOOP
```

---

[EXIT WHEN statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS402)

> The EXIT WHEN statement exits the current iteration of a loop when the
>   condition in its WHEN clause is true, and transfers control to the end
>   of either the current loop or an enclosing labeled loop.
>
> Each time control reaches the EXIT WHEN statement, the condition in
>   its WHEN clause is evaluated. If the condition is not true, the EXIT
>   WHEN statement does nothing. To prevent an infinite loop, a statement
>   inside the loop must make the condition true

Simple example:

```
i := 0;
LOOP
  ....
  ....
  EXIT WHEN i > 9;
  i := i + 1;
END LOOP;
```